# How could I have a helper class that contains app wide settings in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

In Swift, I was used to having a Helper class for app-wide settings. I had used Static Functions to return values, allowing me to make global changes fairly easily. Not sure if this is good practice or not - still a junior dev.

I'm learning to develop with SwiftUI, and this type of sharing doesn't seem possible. What would be the best approach to setting a specific type of font everywhere in the app (across all views)?

For example, instead of

```
Text("Hello World").font(.custom("runda", 20))
```

I would like to do something like:

```
StandardText("Hello World")
```

Which returns the same value. The benefit of this would mean that if I were to make theme changes in the future, changing them in one location would be a lot easier than manipulating 20 instances of where I'd used the specific font. Any tips greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to make it via function, this gives possibility to return `Text` type, so make available all Text-native modifiers

```
func StandardText<S>(_ text: S) -> Text where S: StringProtocol {
    Text(text).font(.custom("runda", size: 20))
}
```

and overload for localized keys

```
func StandardText(_ key: LocalizedStringKey, tableName: String? = nil, bundle: Bundle? = nil, comment: StaticString? = nil) -> Text {
    Text(key, tableName: tableName, bundle: bundle, comment: comment).font(.custom("runda", size: 20))
}
```